# Is it possible to render direct3d graphics over tcp/ip or another network protocol?

Tags: graphics, 3d, rendering, visualization, cluster-computing

I have 3 machines which I would like to setup as a cluster for distributed rendering of 3d graphics, more specific Direct3d. I can do this with Opengl using Wiregl (http://graphics.stanford.edu/software/wiregl/) or better yet Chromium. Does a solution exist for doing the same with Direct3d?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 
What version of Direct3d are you using.

Direct3D 10.1 on windows 7 allows for remote rendering.

Bob.